# Is it safe to remove screws from a 4x4 support beam without compromising it?

Tags: ceiling, structural, beam

We have a home with a basement which has one room containing a 4x4 beam in the ceiling. Yesterday I screwed more than ten 2" #6 and 3-1/2" #10 screws into the beam for a project I was working on before deciding that I should re-evaluate the project and not attach to the beam.

Will there be any structural integrity issues by removing the screws entirely?

If so, would it be best to re-screw the screws in to essentially fill in the void? According to the IBC codes that I've read it mentions that as long as there's not a hole drilled in excess of 60% of the beam diameter that it will still be "at code".

Comment: Is it a beam, or a _post_? 4x4 is very odd for a beam in a house built in the last hundred years. What does it carry?

Comment: Just to note that holes in beams (which this question doesn’t apply to) is a nuanced topic — not just a number like 60%. If in the future you actually drill big holes, read up.

Comment: The beam hole diameter maximum is 33%, but there needs to be 2" of good material above and below such holes. For your 3-1/2" beam, then, the maximum hole diameter is 0".

Comment: … and that 0” hole can’t be close to the ends…

Answer (score 15):

To add further clarity to FreeMan's answer, *removing* the screws doesn't change the equation. Any hypothetical weakening occurred when you drove the screws into the wood. At that point, some fibers were severed, some were *separated*, and some were just mashed up. *That* is where the situation changed. Removing the screws does nothing further to the strength of the member.

Heavy timbers check (crack lengthwise) substantially in almost all cases anyway. Screws do little that checking doesn't, so they aren't considered a hazard to the integrity of the member.

To take the question to its logical extreme, you'd have to run large screws very close together in a straight line across the member to substantially weaken it. I mean so close together that they're touching or overlapping.

Comment: Mostly right as long as one only regard tensile forces (at a theoretical beam starting at the lower half, being strongest at the edge) Removing it will indeed change the theoretical equation where the holes can not take up any compression. So the force either has to flow around the hole or the continum is locally collapsing until the hole is closed. Regarding the deformation afterwards one is then at the initial "hole"-less situation or the beam is "screwed"

Comment: Good grief. This isn't titanium in the Blackbird.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you put all the screws within a couple of inches of each other (which would be an issue whether you removed them or not), you will not cause any sort of issue in the beam strength by removing them and/or leaving them out.

The beam will not be significantly weaker with them removed, and replacing the screws will not provide any significant strengthening of the beam. You can, of course, replace them if it makes you feel better.

The only reasonable way of strengthening the beam would be to fill the holes with dowels, but you'd have to make *larger* holes to get and sort of significant dowel into them, so it's just not worth it.

Comment: Question for the inverse - at what point (screw size, depth, position on the beam itself, etc) does screwing into the beam weaken its integrity? Ie these 10-20 #2 screws, by screwing them in, spaced between 10 and 20" apart, how much of the integrity (roughly) could be considered compromised?

Comment: Feel free to ask that as a whole new question, @Helixdnb, since this site doesn't deal well with questions in comments unless they're asking for specific clarification about the details of the given answer. However, I think you've already got your answer - so long as the hole is less than 50-60% of the beam diameter, and it's located in the center of the beam, you'll be fine.

Comment: Roughly, though, I'd expect about zero.

Comment: The other way to strengthen the beam might be to put a reinforcing plate across the bottom of the area affected. Or you could sister the beam, of course. Both are overkill for this simple case unless there's a lot more to it than we've been told.

Answer (score 10):

For fasteners with diameter less than 1/4", Chapter 12 of the [National Design Specification](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/) prescribes zero fastener strength reduction based on fastener spacing and end distance. See 12.5.1.1.

I suppose that 12.1.5.7 puts splitting outside the scope of the NDS:

> Edge distances, end distances, and fastener spacings shall be sufficient to prevent splitting of the wood.

If it hasn't split already, then you're okay regardless of whether you leave the screws in or remove them. I might remove half of the 3-1/2" screws and install them to bridge the potential splitting plane of the other screws, but that feels like paranoia. A 4×4 is pretty useless outside of compressive post loads, so I suspect that your 4×4 beam doesn't do much anyway.

The IRC's maximum hole spec for floor joists and beams is D/3 with 2" of good material above and below such holes. That makes 0" your maximum hole diameter given your 3-1/2" beam depth. There's a 60% hole size spec for sistered bearing wall studs, where that has nothing to do with floor joists or beams.